# Intercepting a WCF Service with Autofac

Tags: autofac

I am attempting to intercept methods on a WCF service server side with the following registration:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<Service>().As<IServiceContract>().InstancePerLifetimeScope()
                .EnableInterfaceInterceptors().InterceptedBy(typeof(MethodInterceptor));
```

however, when I do the service endpoint disappears.  The WCF service is hosted inside a Windows Service.  Any ideas?

The exception I receive is as follows:

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at`http://localhost:8000/endpointaddress`that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

The MethodInterceptor is registered as follows:

```
containerBuilder.Register(componentContext => new MethodInterceptor(invocation =>
{
    return new NLogToLoggerAdaptor(LogManager.GetLogger(invocation.InvocationTarget.GetType().FullName));
})).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: So your wcf service is selfhosted? So you post your servicehost setup code? Has your code worked before added the `EnableInterfaceInterceptors` part?

Comment: Yes, if I remove the second line of the code sample the endpoint works fine.

Comment: What do you mean on "the service endpoint disappers"? Have you registered your `MethodInterceptor` in the container with `builder.RegisterType<MethodInterceptor>();`?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the exception and interceptor registration.

Comment: Your posted code should just work. There is something else in your code which causing this problem what you haven't shown here. I was not able to repro your issue with the following test app: https://gist.github.com/nemesv/6f89888bb6452c64bfd6. Please try to repro the issue in this test app and probably you will figure out what causing the problem in your app.